# MSP432 : Error connecting to the target: (Error -615 @ 0x0)

Tags: css, texas-instruments, msp432, e2e

I am trying to debug code on MSP432P401R design board using XDS110 emulator with CCSV 7.0.0..
When I debug code it is showing following error:
CS_DAP_0: Error connecting to the target: (Error -615 @ 0x0) The target failed to see a correctly formatted SWD header. The  connection to the target may be unreliable. Try lowering the  TCLK setting before trying again. (Emulation package 9.2.0.00002).
I have tried all the following solutions posted on e2e forum:-

1. Factory reset -  same error occurs when I right click-> connect target on the device under non-debuggable devices after rightclick->show all cores.
2. Changing JTAG/SWD mode - I tried all the modes that are present in the drop down menu and factory reset did not work with any of them.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried replacing your cables? I've locked two of my boards out today, but I get error -614.

Comment: Also you are probably better off posting here: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/other