# MSP-EXP432P401R : Debugging fails with 'JTAG Communication Error'

Tags: msp432

I have a problem with the  MSP-EXP432P401R. After connecting, it runs for some time but after some time suddenly the board gets disconnected. The exact error message is:

CORTEX_M4_0: JTAG Communication Error: (Error -615 @ 0x0) The target failed to see a correctly formatted SWD header. The  connection to the target may be unreliable. Try lowering the  TCLK setting before trying again. (Emulation package 5.1.641.0)

CORTEX_M4_0: Breakpoint Manager: Remove job failed: Register/ write failure[22005]

Comment: Without much inside into the subject matter: *Did* you try to lower the TCLK setting?!

Comment: Your problem (or at least connection problems in general) doesn't seem uncommon.  A quick google search found [this page](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/ccs_debugging_jtag_connectivity_issues.html). Did you try any of the suggestions there?

Comment: Also, there is a dup, I'll vote to close (so that all efforts are concentrated in one place). Oh, I cannot dup this because the other question didn't have any answers. Anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64674811/3150802